# ndk-debug crashed suddenly. gdb.setup: Permission denied

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I was debugging my natives libraries with the ndk-gdb and 
suddenly it does not works!.. when I try launch it  through Cygwin I 
get this:

> cp: missing destination file operand after `/cygdrive/c/User/admin/ 
>   workspace/threadTest/obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup'
>
> Try `cp --help' for more information. 
>   /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5b/ndk-gdb: line 576: /cygdrive/c/User/admin/ 
>   workspace/threadTest/obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup: Permission denied
>
> /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5b/ndk-gdb: line 577: /cygdrive/c/User/admin/ 
>   workspace/threadTest/obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup: Permission denied

P.D: device-> Samsung GT-P1000, debugging on windows, same problem in the emulator 
Any idea? 
Thaks!

Answer (score 0):

> cp: missing destination file operand after `/cygdrive/c/User/admin/ workspace/threadTest/obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup'

This error message is by the following line in ndk-gdb script.

```
cp -f $GDBSETUP_INIT $GDBSETUP
```

$GDBSETUP_INIT is empty, it comes from

```
GDBSETUP_INIT=`get_build_var_for_abi NDK_APP_GDBSETUP $COMPAT_ABI`
```

And then, get_build_var_for_abi is

```
get_build_var_for_abi ()
{
    if [ -z "$GNUMAKE" ] ; then
        GNUMAKE=make
    fi
    $GNUMAKE --no-print-dir -f $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/core/build-local.mk -C $PROJECT DUMP_$1 APP_ABI=$2
}
```

Thus, make doesn't work correctly, I guess. Have you installed GNU make with cygwin setup?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I was debugging but, suddenly, now, I can't

Comment: Anyway, Does "make --no-print-dir -f $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/core/build-local.mk  DUMP_NDK_APP_GDBSETUP APP_ABI=armeabi" work?